# UITableView: Painting-Behavior of Header- and Footer-View

Tags: ios, uitableview

Why does the header and footer of a tableview always stays on top of the view hierarchy, but not the cells of the table?

Here is what I got:

- A table view with custom cells, a footer and a header
- A Navigationbar with a menu-Button on the right
- When the user taps the menu-button, a semi-transparent menu (UIView) fades in from the top, but not over the navigationbar, only over the view of my tableviewcontroller
- When the user tabs a menu-button, the menu slides back to (0,-menuHeight)
- But when the menu is over the header, this menu-region is behind my header

I anchored the menu on the view of my tableviewcontroller, beacause I want the navigationbar allways be visible. the solution to anchor it on the navigationbar solves the problem with the header-view, but covers the navigationbar.

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem? Why are the cells painted correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not interfere directly with the internal view hierarchy of `UITableView`. Apple is free to order a table view's subviews as they see fit (and change it in future releases).

Instead, place the table view and your menu view into a common container view and make the latter the main view of your view controller. That way, you can be certain that your menu view will always be above the table view.

Comment: Ok - I changed my design - but now I do not get touch-events in my table. -> please see my new answer below

Comment: You should not add an answer that contains a question. Edit your original question instead. I also do not believe it's a good idea to reset self.tableView to another view. AFAIK, the tableView property of UITableViewController just returns its view outlet by default. In other words, don't use a UITableViewController anymore. Use a normal UIViewController instead.

Comment: Ok - do you mean, that I should create a new viewController and add the tableviewcontrollers view into it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my design, but now I do not get touch-events in my table.

But when I add this method - I see, that I'm touching the tableviewcontroller...

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    NSLog(@"ShieldingViewController received touch");
    [self.buttonMenu shieldingViewTouched];
}
```

Here is what I changed:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y = 0;

    UIView *rootView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame];
    rootView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;


    // Setup the table view
    UITableView *newTableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:viewFrame style:self.tableView.style];
    newTableView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
    newTableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor];


    UIView *menuLayerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 500)];


    self.tableView = newTableView;

    [rootView addSubview:self.tableView];
    [rootView addSubview: menuLayerView];
    self.view = rootView;

    [[CustomNavigationController instance] setCurrentViewForMenu: menuLayerView];
    [[CustomNavigationController instance] showMenuInNavigationBarForController:self];

    [newTableView release];
    [menuLayerView release];
    [rootView release];
}
```